# count and sum in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, sum

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 8
        )

)
```

I want  count of each key value...and their sum...eg. array 1 contains 3 key , array 2 contains 3 key and array 3 contains 6 keys and array 4 contains 6 keys and their sum..eg .18

Comment: @Priyanka sawant add language tag. I think it is php

Comment: yes itz in php @rahul tripathi

Comment: @Priyankasawant I have an answer on how you get also the sum of the value for each array.

Comment: `$a = array_map('count', $yourArray)` to return an array containing the value count in each array, `$b = array_sum($a)` to get the sum of the values in `$a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
$tempArray = array(0=>array(0=>"12",1=>"15",2=>"6"), 1=>array(0=>"6",1=>"9",2=>"11"), 2=>array(0=>"6",1=>"13",2=>"15",3=>"2",4=>"4",5=>"9"));

foreach($tempArray as $key=>$array)
{
    echo $key . " Array have " . count($array) . " elements<br><br>";
}
```

**Output:**

Array 0 have 3 keys

Array 1 have 3 keys

Array 2 have 6 keys

Comment: $flat = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)), 0);  this worked for me...

Comment: Yeah...
I have provided you only count of each inner array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below. It loops and get the number of keys per array and the sum of the values on each array.

```
<?php
$tester = array(0=>array(0=>12,1=>15,2=>6), 1=>array(0=>6,1=>9,2=>11), 2=>array(0=>6,1=>13,2=>15,3=>2,4=>4,5=>9));


for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($tester); $i++) {
    $sum = 0;
    for ($ii=0; $ii < sizeof($tester[$i]); $ii++) { 
        $sum += $tester[$i][$ii];
    }
    echo "Array $i has " . sizeof($tester[$i]) . " Keys. The sum of values on Array $i : $sum <br>";
}

?>
```

**Output:**

Array 0 has 3 Keys. The sum of values on Array 0 : 33

Array 1 has 3 Keys. The sum of values on Array 1 : 26

Array 2 has 6 Keys. The sum of values on Array 2 : 49